# How to optimize with two implicit, and possibly coupled, systems in OpenMDAO?

Tags: python, openmdao

I've been referring to the Sellar MDA and BalanceComp tutorials, but I'm unable to formulate an OpenMDAO architecture to optimize a coupled system of implicit equations of the type:

> Minimize the function `F` with design variables `x, y` such that the following nonlinear equations are simultaneously satisfied as constraints:
>
> `R(x, y, z) = f(x, y, c) - g(x, y, d) = 0`
>
> `S(x, y, z) = f(x, y, c) - h(x, y, d) = e`
>
> with constants `c, d, e`.

So my idea is to let `F, f, g, h` be `ExplicitComponent` classes, and let `R, S` be `Group` classes that use `BalanceComp` (one inside each!) to determine their respective solutions, because the systems may be used independently in other applications. The constants `c, d, e` can be fed via an `IndepVarComp`, I believe.

Solving the system together involves creating a `Group` component (call it, say, `ImpMDA`) with `R, S` inside it using a `Group` like `cycle` from the Sellar tutorial.

My main issue is how to "synchronize" `x, y` globally across the two systems in the cycle. Should `R`'s results be fed to `S`'s and vice versa? As they're being solved simultaneously, I would assume they're coupled.

Please note that `x, y` may come from some other, separate components, and hence feeding them as a vector is difficult unless some `ExplicitComponent` like `Lister` is created, which takes inputs and generates a vector to feed to `ImpMDA`.

While a specific implementation on a simpler toy case (if possible) would be very helpful, I would really appreciate it if I receive some general insight into modeling this problem in OpenMDAO anyway.

For the specific use-case, consider the minimization of aircraft fuel burn (objective function) with respect to variation of wing area (design variable) while trying to maintain pitch trim (implicit system 1) and pitch stability (implicit system 2) at all operating points in flight, hence determining the horizontal tail area and wing location. The center of pressure (dependent on wing area) matching the center of gravity is the requirement for pitch trim, and similarly for the neutral point for pitch stability, hence the design variable plays a role in the systems.

EDIT:

Here is a Python example of the modular approach I'm looking for:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, minimize

def f(xs, c): return -xs[0]**2 + xs[1] + c          # ExplicitComponent 1
def g(xs, d): return -xs[0]**3 + xs[1]**2 - d       # ExplicitComponent 2
def h(xs, d): return xs[0] + xs[1]**2 + d           # ExplicitComponent 3

# This function is to quickly generate residual functions shown in the question.
# The OpenMDAO implementations for different residual functions will be done either 
# via BalanceComp or ImplicitComponent, and may not share the same equation "setup" as here.
def residualer(f1, f2, a=6, b=4, const=0):           
    return lambda xs: f1(xs, a) - f2(xs, b) + const 

def F(xs):                                          # Objective function
    return xs[0]**2 - xs[1]**2 - 5

x0 = [-2, 2]                                        # Initial guess

# Problem 1
x1_opt = minimize(F, x0, 
                 method='trust-constr',
                 constraints={ 'type': 'eq', 'fun': residualer(f, g, a=1, b=2) }, 
                 options = { 'disp': False } )

print(x1_opt, '\n\n')


# Problem 2
m, n = 5, 6
def coupled(xs):                                    # Coupling the equations 
    return [residualer(f, g)(xs), residualer(f, h, a=4, b=3, const=m*n)(xs)] 

x2_opt = minimize(F, x0, 
                 method='trust-constr',
                 constraints={ 'type': 'eq', 'fun': coupled }, 
                 options = { 'disp': False } )

print(x2_opt)
```

which returns:

```
         cg_niter: 22
     cg_stop_cond: 2
           constr: [array([-8.8817842e-16])]
      constr_nfev: [102]
      constr_nhev: [0]
      constr_njev: [0]
   constr_penalty: 3.2410415627552283
 constr_violation: 8.881784197001252e-16
   execution_time: 0.028232574462890625
              fun: -10.302775637731996
             grad: array([ 1.19209290e-07, -4.60555129e+00])
              jac: [array([[-5.96046448e-08, -3.60555129e+00]])]
  lagrangian_grad: array([ 1.95345288e-07, -8.88178420e-16])
          message: '`xtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
           method: 'equality_constrained_sqp'
             nfev: 102
             nhev: 0
              nit: 23
            niter: 23
             njev: 0
       optimality: 1.9534528835387254e-07
           status: 2
          success: True
        tr_radius: 5.238777835236851e-09
                v: [array([-1.2773501])]
                x: array([1.17707733e-08, 2.30277564e+00]) 


         cg_niter: 0
     cg_stop_cond: 1
           constr: [array([4.4408921e-14, 0.0000000e+00])]
      constr_nfev: [36]
      constr_nhev: [0]
      constr_njev: [0]
   constr_penalty: 2.1867764273118655
 constr_violation: 4.440892098500626e-14
   execution_time: 0.012656688690185547
              fun: -24.59492687150548
             grad: array([  5.27636947, -10.30629829])
              jac: [array([[15.60368701, -9.30629829],
       [-6.27636948, -9.30629823]])]
  lagrangian_grad: array([1.77635684e-15, 0.00000000e+00])
          message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
           method: 'equality_constrained_sqp'
             nfev: 36
             nhev: 0
              nit: 12
            niter: 12
             njev: 0
       optimality: 1.7763568394002505e-15
           status: 1
          success: True
        tr_radius: 4.9172480000000025
                v: [array([-0.55882674, -0.54862737])]
                x: array([2.63818474, 5.1531491 ])
```

Comment: The usage of external code comps isn't really necessary to address any of the specifics in this question. Also, your statement about matching pitch and stability across all flight conditions implies that you actually have large vectors of coupled equations. Please try to boil this down to a more compact representative example, and even if you can't formulate it in OpenMDAO provide the basic equations or a stand alone python script that does the convergence you're seeking. As posed, this question is too broad to give a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ExplicitComponent` (edited the question). I'll try to prepare a Python script and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @JustinGray Added the Python example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at doing this in a modular way.  Since the script is fairly large, its on a github gist [here](https://gist.github.com/robfalck/5b1de750ef7d1737b8a5548328f8f5fe).

Here Residualer is a group that serves the purpose of your residualer function.  In its initialize method, I defined options that are specific for each instantiation.

Each instantiation creates its own subsystems for `f`, `g`, and `h`.  In practice, I'd probably make a single component that outputs `f`, `g`, and `h` since they're simple equations and independent of one another.

`problem1_optimizer()` and `problem2_optimizer()` use scipy optimizer with equality constraints on the residuals, as your examples do.

The N2 for the problem2_optimizer is:

[image: problem2_optimizer N2]

`problem2_solver()` uses the `use_solver` option on residualer to include a balance component and a NewtonSolver.  This balance component adds an implicit variable for each element in `x`, which has a corresponding residual (R or S).  These two scalar values (`x1` and `x2`) are muxed into the `x` variable and then passed to the appropriate components by promotion.  As coded, this requires that we have a single residual for each scalar implicit variable, and so it only works on your second example.  Note the unconnected inputs in the following are due to the fact that our balance comp is only taking in one variable and using an assumed value of 0.0 for the other side of the equation.  Theres no optimization in this second case since there are only two variables and two unknowns, and therefore no more degrees of freedom for optimization.

[image: problem2_solver N2]

Comment: This is great and very instructive. Thanks a lot for taking the time to write it! I have a few questions about redesigning this, though. Say I want to put one `BalanceComp` in each equation (`R` and `S` as groups) so they are implicit components instead of explicit; in this situation, both `R` and `S` will have their own `x_0` and `x_1` each that need to be synced with each other for solving the coupled system. Is this possible to implement or is the design setup not feasible?

Comment: Implicit components define the implicit variables `x_i` and their associated residuals.  Solvers in OpenMDAO satisfy ALL residuals at or below their group by varying all implicit variables at or below their group.  So yes, a single Newton solver in a group that contains both R and S will simultaneously satisfy both when it is converged.

Comment: Sometimes this gets tricky to think about:  Should `x_1` be associated with `R` or `S`?  Generally you can think of them as a system of two variables and two residuals that the solver will just take care of for you.  This code would probably be easier to handle if we passed `x_1` and `x_2` as separate inputs to `f`, `g`, and `h` so we could do away with the mux.